# Vue-Router global function execution on route change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

So my query is that is there a way to get Vue-Router to execute a function/method after route changes? More specifically, after the route has been mounted successfully.

Currently, I do loading function that evaluated to true once the user clicks away from the initial screen. And each page has a mounted function (repeated across all my vue pages) that sets the loading to false.

I want to have it such that the router detects this change, sees if the new routed component has been mounted and then executes a function to set the loading to false.

I use a dedicated router.js file to contain all my routes and params for it and then call that file in the main app.js file that mounts the view for the user.